# How to get enum in thymeleaf in kotlin project?

Tags: kotlin, enums, thymeleaf

How to get enum in thymeleaf in kotlin project?
This is an enum file.

```
<!-- language: lang-kotlin -->

enum class SessionEnum(val displayValue: String) {
    USERNAME("username")
}
```

I tried to get the enum value in thymeleaf in this way, but it failed.

```
<p>Login User：<span th:text="${T(com.project.example.authapp.types.SessionEnum).USERNAME)}"></span></p>
```

I would appreciate it if someone with a good understanding of kotlin could tell me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an extra `)` in the template. Also, if you want to show `displayValue` i.e. "username" instead of "USERNAME" add `.displayValue`:

```
<p>Login User：<span th:text="${T(com.project.example.authapp.types.SessionEnum).USERNAME.displayValue}"></span></p>
```